# How to Query/Filter M2M 'through' object in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have the following basic model…

```
  class Campaign(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=80, unique=True)
    recipients = models.ManyToManyField('Person', blank=True, null=True, through='Recipient')


  class Recipient(models.Model):
    campaign = models.ForeignKey(Campaign)
    person = models.ForeignKey('Person')


  class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
```

I'd like to have a queryset that queries all Person objects that are not within a given Campaign.

It'd be nice if it was as easy as:

```
Person.objects.all().exclude(<mycampaign>.recipients.all())
```

but we know that doesn't work.

To be more specific, I'm trying to get this to work in a form class as follows and the Q object comment seems right but I can't get it to work… Here's my form:

```
class RecipientsForm(forms.Form):
  def __init__(self, campaign, *args, **kwargs): 
    self.campaign = campaign
    self.helper = FormHelper()
    self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit','Add',css_class='primaryAction'))
    self.helper.layout = Layout(
        Fieldset(
          '',
          'recipients',
          css_class='inlineLabels')
      )
    return super(RecipientsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

  recipients = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
  # old queryset queryset=Person.objects.all(),
                 queryset=Person.objects.filter(~Q(id__in=self.campaign.recipients.all())),
                 widget=forms.widgets.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
                 label="Add Recipients",
                 required=True,)

  def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, commit=True):
    recipients = self.cleaned_data['recipients']
    for person in recipients:
      recipient = Recipient(campaign=self.campaign,person=person)
      recipient.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will do it.

```
from django.db.models import Q
Person.objects.filter(~Q(id__in=<mycampaign>.recipients.all())
```

Comment: Can you look at my form class and tell me what I'm doing wrong? I've updated the question content—

Comment: When you have it with the old queryset (queryset=Person.objects.all()) does it show all of them? Also, verify access to the self.campaign, you can do a simple `raise Exception(self.campaign.name)` just above `recipients = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField()` I wonder if the self.campaign is not visible in the main section of your class, perhaps because it is not initialized at execution. If this is the case, you may need to only declare the recipients in the class and have the __init__() method initialize the recipients list based on the self.campaign.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the answer… the problem was that my form was for the Recipient object instead of the Campaign object… the Furbeenator answer was a good step in the right direction… along with some help on the django IRC

```
class RecipientsForm(forms.ModelForm):

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.campaign = kwargs.pop('campaign', None)
    super(RecipientsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    if self.instance and self.campaign:
      self.fields['recipients'] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Person.objects.filter(~Q(id__in=self.campaign.recipients.all())),
        widget=forms.widgets.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        label='Recipients', help_text='Pick the recipients to add to the campaign',
        required=False,
      )
    elif self.campaign:
      self.fields['recipients'] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Person.objects.filter(~Q(id__in=self.campaign.recipients.all())),
        widget=forms.widgets.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        label='Recipients', help_text='Pick the recipients to add to the campaign',
        required=False,
      )
    else:
      pass

  def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, commit=True):
    recipients = self.cleaned_data['recipients']
    for person in recipients:
      recipient = Recipient(campaign=self.campaign,person=person)
      recipient.save()

  class Meta:
    model = Campaign
    fields = ['recipients',]
```

Comment: Awesome, glad you got it figured out.